# Rooting an asus tablet

Tags: rooting

I have tried rooting my asus anpad but failed to unlock it's dastoor drivers. is there any process to unlock it or any other method to root asus zenpad. How can any asus zenpad z370cg tablet be rooted?

Comment: ASUS no longer seems to supply fastboot unlocking for newer Zen devices, and unless an unofficial method comes out (which is unlikely considering your device's popularity), you can't just go into bootloader and unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried KingRoot.  I don't own that particular tablet, but I know that many devices can be rooted with the KingRoot program. You could also try looking at XDA-Dev's site as they tend to have a list of tools for each particular devices.  Hope this helps!